# Parallelize a series of operations respecting data dependencies

Tags: python, algorithm, compiler-construction

In a big string of `{multiplication|division|addition|subtraction}` commands (e.g. `a * b * c * d`).
That I have in the form:

```
1: a * #2
2: b * #3
3: c *  d
```

Is there an algorithm for transforming this into something that looks like this:

```
1:  a *  b
2:  c *  d
3: #1 * #2
```

So that I can run command #1 and #2 in parallel, while at the same time respecting data dependencies and operation precedence/parentheses?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing where you'd abuse `ast` and run into [Greenspun's tenth rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule) (by checking if there are multiple immediately-nested operations of the same kind, linearizing them, and then executing them in parallel)

Comment: You could probably write such an algorithm, but it might be difficult.  Are you trying to achieve performance, or something else?

Comment: No particular reason this is my toy compiler and I would like to work with data dependency and concurrency. But I don't know of an efficient algorithm that will work in every case. If I fix it for one test-case, some other gets ruined, so I was wondering if this is a problem already described and solved somewhere.

Comment: Dependencies? Topological sort...